# {if...else} how to display an image if a mysql field equals ex.1

Tags: php, if-statement

i have a question:
i have a mysql table that has values such as `pages_viewed` that increments every time a user accesses a page such as 1,2,3 etc.
My question is simple how do i display an image when the field equals or is more than 1?

like

```
select pages_viewed from table;
if field pages_viewed > 1 than echo images/image.png
```

pardon my php i'm not too good at it.

i've been reading here and in other forums but all i can find is drupal or wordpress.

Comment: love how you gave an example of how pages_viewed gets incremented!

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
header('Content-Type: image/png')
echo file_get_contents(images/image.png)
```

Comment: ,i need this to be conditional, if the field equals or is more than ex.1 than display an image from my images folder. i am already using headers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything basically short of database connection, table name, field name.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("select * from table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    # Any other code to post the page information
    if($row['pages_viewed'] > 0) echo "<img src='images/image.png' />";
    # Any other code to post the page information
}
```